# React Native, Express, Node, MongoDB stack

Tags: mongodb, react-native, express, react-redux, axios

I am currently working on my first react-native application.  I have some starter code from MERN stack projects that I have previously worked on, and in those projects, linking the frontend and backend wasn’t an issue.  I am using redux for its reducers and actions to try to send data to my mongodb database.  In my redux actions, I am using axios for API calls, but none of them work.

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/mernn-to-do-app-dab1e3173493

I also tried running the server and the expo app at the same time (like in the link above), but it is not working.  Sometimes, the server side will coincide with the client side and result in the error Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000.

Does anyone know an easy way to set up an express, node, and mongodb backend to a react-native app?

Comment: hello, have you found an answer. Im also stuck in this problem

Comment: and how do you connect the back end with the front end using express? i mean does expo port number and express port number can't run on the same port so how did you do it.

Answer (score 0):

BEFORE: Run npm start in the terminal and check the output to see if the terminal print something like server.js nodemon src/server.js.

REASON: If you do then your scripts are calling server.js twice, which is causing this Error.

FIX: I had the same issue and fixed it by fixing my package.json in root folder and also the package.json in the server folder.

AFTER: you should see the terminal print nodemon src/server.js when you run your script.

Hope this helps.